basic material not exporting with glb
newbie here, but I've tried researching as much as I can already and nothing's working.
I'm trying to export a basic glb because Shopify supports them(this is my first time working with glbs, but I read any documentation I could find as to why this would happen and nothing matches or helps), but no matter what I try, I can't get ANY material to export and it just exports as solid white.
I know there's a lot of things glb's can't do/export etc, but this is super basic and I can't figure out the reasonings behind why it's not working.
I have a simple bsdf shader with a png image texture to put the logo on the front of the t-shirt.

but once I export (and I've tried ever combination of export settings that even slightly would Make sense) it just exports as a solid white model, which is extra weird cuz white's not the base or even the in viewport colour.

any advice or help would be GRATELY appreciated as im hoping to do more of these to update my Shopify store.

This is the section on exporting materials in the Blender Manual.

I've read through all of that and followed all the directions to a T and it's still not working,  I've been working on this for days with no advancements. it's not making sense to me why it wouldn't work.
I'm only using 1 BSDF principal shader with a single image texture input into it and no matter what I try it keeps only coming out as white. I even tried some special glb shader add on that one article suggested on here, but that didn't work either.
if anyone can provide ANY insight it would be greatly appreciated. I can answer any further questions if I haven't explained it well enough
